# Why do i get java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol?

Tags: java, io

I am trying to build a java program that downloads files, but i get and exemption every time.

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol
```

the code for the URL is

```
URL site;

String urlString = "http://www.cs.drexel.edu/~spiros/teaching/CS575/slides/java.pdf‎";

site = new URL("urlString");
```

I have also tried:

```
String urlString = "www.cs.drexel.edu/~spiros/teaching/CS575/slides/java.pdf‎";
```

i have tried printing urlString to the console, it is being set correctly to ether one accordingly in each test. What am i missing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is wrong :

```
site = new URL("urlString");
```

Use the variable:

```
site = new URL(urlString);
```

Comment: i feel stupid now, i should have realized i passed it wrong to URL, i was to sure of myself

Answer (score 5):

`"urlString"` is a string literal for the literal value `urlString`.
That isn't a valid URL.

You probably want to reference the variable, not write a string literal.

Comment: i feel stupid now, i should have realized i passed it wrong to URL, i was to sure of myself